# Delete regex group from matching line using grep or sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a file with contents as this:

```
- 2 equal files of size 288903252
- 2 equal files of size 284164096
  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
- 2 equal files of size 277436598
- 2 equal files of size 161356649
  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"
- 35 equal files of size 97078976
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacwu.inf_amd64_9934c34dc6ca0c4b\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamwu.inf_amd64_d4715679184092a8\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaowu.inf_amd64_785608ed2524cdea\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvblwu.inf_amd64_31f54e2d1ba058d5\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
```

I want to delete those lines with `- X equal files of size` without having actual file paths following them. For example first and third bullet point:

```
- 2 equal files of size 284164096
  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
- 2 equal files of size 161356649
  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"
- 35 equal files of size 97078976
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacwu.inf_amd64_9934c34dc6ca0c4b\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamwu.inf_amd64_d4715679184092a8\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaowu.inf_amd64_785608ed2524cdea\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvblwu.inf_amd64_31f54e2d1ba058d5\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
```

I formed a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Fb8ui7/6) that matches these lines:

```
(^-.*\n)-
```

which can be checked in action at above link. I want to delete that first group which is essentially the whole line. But not able to guess how do I do the same with `grep` or `sed`. Can we do this in single command?

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
sed '/^-/{N;/\n-/D}' file

- 2 equal files of size 284164096
  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
- 2 equal files of size 161356649
  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"
- 35 equal files of size 97078976
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacwu.inf_amd64_9934c34dc6ca0c4b\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamwu.inf_amd64_d4715679184092a8\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaowu.inf_amd64_785608ed2524cdea\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvblwu.inf_amd64_31f54e2d1ba058d5\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
```

Portable version for any version of sed

```
sed -e '/^-/{N' -e '/\
-/D' -e '}' file
```

If you want to remove the last line if it is `-`

```
sed -e '/^-/{$d' -e 'N' -e '/\
-/D' -e '}' file
```

Comment: Nice, did not know that (upvoted, will edit my own answer). For those trying this on macOS, you'll need GNU sed (can be installed with Homebrew).

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Added a portable version for mac.

Comment: idk about the rest of it but `\n` isn't portable. To portably use a newline in sed you need a backslash followed by a literal newline. It would also undesirably print the line if the last line in the file was one of the `- 2 equal files of size 284164096` type of lines.

Comment: @EdMorton Not sure that was a specification but it is a simple change, and the portability was for mac. Updated anyway.

Comment: I don;t see anything in the post to suggest that `-...` line couldn't be the last one in the file. To me it reads like that's as likely as not. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can just grep it:

```
grep -v -B1 "^-" test_file.txt | grep -v "\-\-"

- 2 equal files of size 284164096
  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
- 2 equal files of size 161356649
  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"
- 35 equal files of size 97078976
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacwu.inf_amd64_9934c34dc6ca0c4b\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamwu.inf_amd64_d4715679184092a8\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaowu.inf_amd64_785608ed2524cdea\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvblwu.inf_amd64_31f54e2d1ba058d5\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
```

How it works? It's merely selecting all lines and the lines before them that don't start with a `-`. The second grep just removes the group separator, some grep versions support `--no-group-separator` so you can do it in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Is <del>pepsi</del> perl okay?

```
cat input.txt | perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/^-.*?\n-/-/smg'
```

The `BEGIN` block allows the multiline search by essentially telling perl that there is no end of line character. Then the `s/` part will substitute any part matching your regex with a `-` (no need for a capturing group).

Oh, and I slightly modified your regex to be greedy, with a `?`. Otherwise, the search being multiline, it would match from the first `-` to the last one, and remove almost everything.

<del>Edit: [here is a lengthy and informative Q/A about multiline search](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string), that shows it will be difficult with `sed`.</del>

Edit2: actually quite easy with a modern `sed`, see @123's answer

Comment: I specifically wanted to do this with `bash` as mastering `bash` over the period of time is also my long term goal...but anyways thanks will have a look...

Comment: Well this is still bash. Here perl is a substitute for sed, not bash. I edited the first line to acknowledge that this answer is offering a substitute that might not satisfy the requirements :)

Comment: @HuguesMoreau It isn't bash at all. Although sed and grep also aren't bash so unsure what OP wants.

Comment: @123 come on... You know what I meant. I wanted to clarify that I did not overlook the bash requirement, but did twist the sed requirement.

Comment: Whilst this works for OP's sample data it won't work reliably for OP's specification. It will remove all lines between two `^-` lines, but conveniently this removes the correct lines in the sample. Try with another `^-` line anywhere in the file other than next to `- 35 equal files of size 97078976`. I'm not sure this can reliably be done using regex alone.

Comment: `((\n|^)-[^\n]+(?=\n-))+` probably comes pretty close actually but will leave a blank line if it matches on the first line.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with the OPs sample data. I get `- 2 equal files of size 284164096;  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso";  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso";- 2 equal files of size 161356649;  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"` output (replaced newlins with `;`s for inclusion in the comment). It will also undesirably print the last line if it's one of the `- ...` lines.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. If you are using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

This will work robustly, efficiently, and portably with any awk on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^ /{print p $0; p=""; next} {p=$0 ORS}' file
- 2 equal files of size 284164096
  "C:\E\100p disk util bak\Softwares\OSs\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
  "H:\Softwares\Linux\gparted-live-0.26.1-1-i686.iso"
- 2 equal files of size 161356649
  "H:\Softwares\Dev Tools\Eclipse\Windows\eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip"
- 35 equal files of size 97078976
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvacwu.inf_amd64_9934c34dc6ca0c4b\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvamwu.inf_amd64_d4715679184092a8\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvaowu.inf_amd64_785608ed2524cdea\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
  "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvblwu.inf_amd64_31f54e2d1ba058d5\NvCplSetupInt.exe"
```